# Floating Action Button does not work. "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init>" happens

Tags: android

I want **Floating Action Buttons** to appear or disappear while scrolling.
But my code doesn't work. 
I checked the other similar questions, But I didn't know the reason.
Please, anyone tell me why these errors happen.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.knkj28.test, PID: 11926
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.knkj28.test.ScrollAwareFABBehavior
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.knkj28.test.ScrollAwareFABBehavior
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:615)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:2652)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:1679)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:109)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:860)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at com.knkj28.test.ListFragment.onCreateView(ListFragment.java:63)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1984)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1028)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19785)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1362)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1611)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1250)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6311)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6217)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.parseBehavior(CoordinatorLayout.java:609)
        ... 64 more
```

Layout file(To shorten code, I deleted constraint attribute.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/play_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 android:id="@+id/fab_add_music_to_playlist"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_36dp"
 android:visibility="visible"
 app:layout_behavior="com.knkj28.test.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"/>

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
  android:id="@+id/fab_delete_music_from_playlist"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_36dp"
  app:layout_behavior="com.knkj28.test.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
  android:visibility="visible"/>

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Subclass of CoordinatorLayout.Behavior
(Full path:"com.knkj28.test.ScrollAwareFABBehavior ")

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<FloatingActionButton> {

    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target,
                               int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed);
            FloatingActionButton mFb1 = (FloatingActionButton) child.findViewById(fab_add_music_to_playlist);
            FloatingActionButton mFb2 = (FloatingActionButton) child.findViewById(R.id.fab_delete_music_from_playlist);
        if (dyConsumed > 0 && ((mFb1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) || (mFb2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE))) {
            mFb1.hide();
            mFb2.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && ((mFb1.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) || (mFb2.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE))) {
            mFb1.show();
            mFb2.show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` - This constructor must be explicitly `public`.

Comment: Thank you. Error disappear. But It doesn't work correctly. onNestedScroll is not called while scrolling.

Comment: You have to return `true` from `onStartNestedScroll()` to receive events in `onNestedScroll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add a scroll listener to the RecyclerView and hide/show the floating action button from their?

```
rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (dy > 0) {
                fab.hide();
            } else {
                fab.show();
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: I tried it. But It doesn't work correctly. Once FAB disappear, It never appears.